# How to prevent from recreating fragments in BottomNavigationView while switching between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I created four `fragments` in `BottomNavigationView`...I want to avoid recreating of `fragment` while switching between `fragments` if it already created...i.e don't want to call `onCreateView()` of `fragment` multiple times(it should call only once).

Comment: AFAIK you should add(not replace) all fragments and use hide/show(call `FragmentTransaction.show()` on current and `FragmentTransaction.hide()` for the rest) ... but why you wana do this?

Comment: Than ViewPager would be better option against BottomNavigationView

Comment: You can use ViewPager along with BottomNavigationView, as described [here](http://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/).